# How can I mock a method which is called after then in jest?

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

I have the following code which downloads a pdf:

```
import html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js'
export const addFooter = (pdf) => {
  const totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages()
  ...
}
export const downloadPDF = async (...) => {
  const pdfContent = document.getElementById("export")
  const opts = {...}
  await html2pdf().from(pdfContent).set(opts).toPdf().get('pdf').then(addFooter).save()
}
```

I would like to be able to mock the save method using jest.

Up until now I have:

```
jest.mock('html2pdf.js', () => () => ({
  from: () => ({
    set: () => ({
      toPdf: () => ({
        get: () => Promise.resolve({
          internal: {
            getNumberOfPages: () => {}
          }
        })
      })
    })
  })
}))
```

But running the tests give me:

```
TypeError: (0 , _html2pdf.default)(...).from(...).set(...).toPdf(...).get(...).then(...).save is not a function
```

Maybe someone have an idea how to mock the save method?

Comment: There you see exactly the problem with mocking things you don't own - that's a complex API you're having to rebuild. Assuming your implementation is correct it seems like `.then` doesn't return a promise, it returns an object with a save method. If you pushed that library call behind an interface you _did_ own, it would be easy to mock that for isolated testing, then do integrated testing to ensure you're using the library correctly.

Comment: Well your `get()` method returns a promise, whose `.then()` method returns another promise, not an object with a `save()` method. Just don't use a promise here, treat `.get().then().save()` just like the other chained methods.

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi. Simple solution and it works!